# on submit button page scrolls up to top instead of form submit after magento2.4.5 upgrade

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, upgrade, magento2.4.4

While submit form it scrolls up to top rather than submit, I have tried with `jQuery('#edit_form')[0].submit();` but it's not calling my validations.

```
submit: function() {
        if (jQuery('#amasty_quote_edit').length) {
    var info = $('order-items_grid').select('input', 'select', 'textarea');
             for(var i=0; i<info.length; i++){
                 if(info[i].dataset.itemId > 0)
                {
                    var itemId = info[i].dataset.itemId;
                    console.log(jQuery("#optionbtn"+itemId).length);
                    if(jQuery("#optionbtn"+itemId).length > 0){
                        if(jQuery(".selected-product-options"+itemId).length > 0){
                             jQuery("#product-options"+itemId+" .mage-error")[0].remove();
                        }else{
                            if(jQuery("#product-options"+itemId+" .mage-error") .length == 0){
                                jQuery("#product-options"+itemId).append("<label class='mage-error'>Please select options.</label>");
                            }
                            jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: (jQuery("#product-options"+itemId).offset().top - 150)});
                             return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
             }
            jQuery('#amasty_quote_edit').submit();
        } else {
            var info = $('order-items_grid').select('input', 'select', 'textarea');
             for(var i=0; i<info.length; i++){
                 if(info[i].dataset.itemId > 0)
                {
                    var itemId = info[i].dataset.itemId;
                    console.log(jQuery("#optionbtn"+itemId).length);
                    if(jQuery("#optionbtn"+itemId).length > 0){
                        if(jQuery(".selected-product-options"+itemId).length > 0){
                             jQuery("#product-options"+itemId+" .mage-error").remove();
                        }else{
                            if(jQuery("#product-options"+itemId+" .mage-error") .length == 0){
                                jQuery("#product-options"+itemId).append("<label class='mage-error'>Please select options.</label>");
                            }
                            jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: (jQuery("#product-options"+itemId).offset().top - 150)});
                             return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
             }
            jQuery('#edit_form').submit();
        }
    },
```

I want to submit the form, I have tried

```
jQuery('#edit_form')[0].submit();
```

but with this code, the validations are not working.

Comment: there was custom shipping method required field validation fired which was not display on the page causing the issue.